# Move variable product short description under attribute dropdows in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

Is there any way I could set or put a product short description under/below the variation but above add to cart button? "The Add to Cart Block is Wrapped up with the Variable selections" can someone help me with this...

I have tried some code but it's not working the way I wanted:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For variable products only, to move the short description under the attribute(s) dropdown(s), try the following instead:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'changing_single_variable_product_summary' );
function changing_single_variable_product_summary() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable')) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20);
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_variations_table', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 10 );
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: thank you for this solution! anyways it's not working on my end... these is my link to my test page: https://dev-test1394.pantheonsite.io/product/test-1/

Comment: @IamDan I tested the code and it works… It will not work with some themes that have already made some customizations on that hook. So it's up to you to find out in your theme where is that customization to make the necessary changes..